# Isoclinic rotation of metric in GR

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am new to General Relativity. Suppose we have a spacetime described by this metric:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
f(r,\theta,\phi)&0&0&0 \\
0&g(r,\theta,\phi)&0&0 \\
0&0&h(r,\theta,\phi)&0 \\
0&0&0&m(r,\theta,\phi)
\end{matrix}\right)$$

What does a isoclinic rotation physically mean for the spacetime?

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks!

Comment: It was the blank lines in the matrix. MathJax can be very fussy about these things :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie yes generally programming languages are very sensitive to such details.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by isoclinic rotation in this context?

Comment: Rotation of the tensor by $180^{\circ}$